# Colorbox "href=myhtml.html#anchor" on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

Trying to call colorbox with javascript function, to open HTML file at specified anchor.

```
function mylink(){
    jQuery().colorbox({
        iframe:true, 
        fastIframe:false, 
        inline:true, 
        width:"85%", 
        height:"85%", 
        href:"../reference.html#myanchor'});
        }
```

Works on desktop browser (MAC Safari), but do not work on iPad iOS7.
Is this new issue with iPad iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I saw something on this recently...
Umm have a look at [this](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?259280-anchor-tag-not-working-in-safari-%28ios%29-for-Iphone-iTouch-iPad)